# Need help in binding dynamic JSON to Highcharts

Tags: json, binding, highcharts

I have the JSON data received from the server as:

```
[{"Text":"TRUCKLOAD","Spend":32323348.4},
{"Text":"NON-SYNDICATED:QUALITATIVE &  QUANTITATIVE","Spend":23270306.54},
{"Text":"SAMPLING & EVENTERVICES","Spend":18924795.75},
{"Text":"OTHER LOGISTICS","Spend":18353919.01},
{"Text":"CONSTRUCTION AND INSTALLATION","Spend":13248733.26},
{"Text":"SECURITY SERVICES","Spend":9210534.97},
{"Text":"TAXES","Spend":8661964.99}]
```

Can anybody help me to bind this data dynamically to a piechart?

Another problem is that the highchart requires me to change the labels as `Name` and a `y` tag of JSON instead of the `Text` and `Spend` tag in my JSON. How do i change my JSON for that? I have scoured the net for the same but all examples only seem to show the binding of JSON from an external file.

Comment: Did you found the solution?I also have the same problem

Comment: @iancoslovak I think he did what I said on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see demos' source [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) and then click view options button.
The best way to do it is format your json on your backend before you receive it.
But if you want to do it, you can use the following code:

```
var json = [{
    "name":"TRUCKLOAD",
    "y":32323348.4
}, {
    "name":"NON-SYNDICATED:QUALITATIVE & QUANTITATIVE",
    "y":23270306.54
}, {
    "name":"SAMPLING & EVENTERVICES",
    "y":18924795.75
}];

var data = [];
for(var i in json) {
    var serie = new Array(json[i].name, json[i].y);
    data.push(serie);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5qxbw/4/)

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to make a change on the backend. is there any property where i can do the assignment for "name" and "y" dynamically.

Comment: No, as you can see on my json I just put in order the data with name for first and then y.

Comment: I agree with Ricardo. If you want to dynamically bind the data,the easiest way to do this is on the back-end.  What are you using: ASP.NET, PHP, Python?  I would iterate through the json using a foreach statement and build the data that way.  This especially holds true if the number of categories changes at all.

Comment: Ricardo, i tried your solution but it says json is undefined in IE7,IE8..now trying to scour the web..

Comment: ok that json error got resolved but i have the new one as 'serie' is undefined, followed by $lineinfo is undefined and then debugger takes me to MicrosoftAjax.js file.. basically the value is undefined for jquery each function.

Comment: @AdnanBaliwala I've updated my answer without use jQuery, try it now :)